# Is apt-mark persistent after a reboot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

More specifically, I would like to permanently ( or at least in the short term) disable updating a particular package. I see that sudo apt-mark hold  will do the job. But I am not sure will the "hold" remain persistent after a reboot. if it's not persistent I will have to run sudo apt-mark hold  before every apt update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt` use own database, plain files which can be seen in `/var/lib/apt`.

`apt-mark` use configuration file `/var/lib/apt/extended_states`

And answer to your question: changes which you made with `apt-mark` will be persistent.